# Error: Unexpected value 'FormGroup' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

Our project structure follows this: [Angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter).

Our project successfully compiles, build and can be seen in the browser. No problems here.

But when we try to run the test cases using `karma and jasmine` we are getting this error.

```
XXXXComponent
   :heavy_multiplication_x: Should Match Current Tab as 1
     Chrome 55.0.2883 (Mac OS X 10.10.5)
   Error: Unexpected value 'FormGroup' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'
       at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:811:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:74048:33)
       at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/src/facade/errors.js:26:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:78913:16)
       at new SyntaxError (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/src/util.js:151:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:6408:16)
       at webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js:475:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:19829:40
       at Array.forEach (native)
       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.js:457:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:19811:54)
       at JitCompiler._loadModules (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/src/jit/compiler.js:165:25 <- config/spec-bundle.js:55462:64)
       at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/src/jit/compiler.js:144:25 <- config/spec-bundle.js:55441:52)
       at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/src/jit/compiler.js:98:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:55395:21)
       at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (webpack:///~/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js:482:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:78583:35)
       at TestBed._initIfNeeded (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:761:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:26731:40)
       at TestBed.createComponent (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:844:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:26814:18)
       at Function.TestBed.createComponent (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:673:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:26643:33)
       at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///src/app/zzzz/yyyy/xxxx.component.spec.ts:20:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:93231:37)
       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:242:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:73479:26)
       at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:73133:39)
       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:241:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:73478:32)
       at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:73350:43)
       at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:102:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:72848:34)
       at ZoneQueueRunner.jasmine.QueueRunner.ZoneQueueRunner.execute (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:132:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:72878:42)
       at ZoneQueueRunner.jasmine.QueueRunner.ZoneQueueRunner.execute (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:132:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:72878:42)
       at webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:129:91 <- config/spec-bundle.js:72875:130
       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:275:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:73512:35)
       at Zone.runTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:73388:47)
       at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:433:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:73670:35)
```

We have imported all these modules in the app.module.ts as required by new angular convention.

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    ...
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ... ],
  providers: [ // expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection
    ENV_PROVIDERS,
    APP_PROVIDERS
  ],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {}
}
```

Our testBed is setup in this way

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
   declarations: [ FormGroup, XXXXComponent ], // declare the test   component
});

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(XXXXComponent);
  comp = fixture.componentInstance; 
});
```

and also

```
testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
  browser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  browser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
```

We have all the latest versions of packages installed.

```
"@angular/common": "~2.4.3",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.4.3",
"@angular/core": "~2.4.3",
"@angular/forms": "~2.4.3",
"@angular/http": "~2.4.3",
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.3",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.3",
"@angular/platform-server": "~2.4.3",
"@angular/router": "~3.4.3",
"karma": "^1.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-webpack": "2.0.1",
"webpack": "2.2.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.9.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.2.0",
"webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"webpack-md5-hash": "~0.0.5",
"webpack-merge": "~2.4.0"
```

Any help in resolving this issue is appreciated.

Comment: remove ``FormGroup`` from declarations and add to providers if you  have injected it. I dont see you importing ``FormGroup`` either.

Comment: get your points and make this an answer

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The error is in your test bed configuration

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [ FormGroup, XXXXComponent ], // declare the test component
});
```

`FormGroup` is not part of your code, it belongs to the `ReactiveFormsModule` and therefore it is invalid for you to declare it. Declaring connotes ownership by an NgModule of that which is declared. You also should not provide it, import it, or export it *directly*. You import it *indirectly* by way of importing `ReactiveFormsModule`, and may export it *indirectly* by way of exporting `ReactiveFormsModule`. You must not declare it. You must not provide it.

So change your configuration call to

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [XXXXComponent], // declare the test component
});
```

Comment: Seriously glad I came across this... So you cannot import unnecessary things when testing... got it.

Comment: @BenRacicot I'm glad this answer helped you. This applies regardless to whether or not you are testing. You actually _can_ list any number of `NgModule`s in `imports` and/or `exports` regardless of whether or not they are used. What you may _not_ do is (1) _declare_ components, directives, pipes and (2) _provide_ services that belong to other `NgModule`s. If this sounds complicated, it is. `NgModule` is a ridiculously complex and unnecessary abstraction that has no value (actually, it has negative value).

Comment: This answer saved my day! And I just want to say that the error message "Unexpected value 'FormGroup' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'" is not helpful at all! If they can say something like "FormGroup is not declarable, must be imported in modules" or telling the relation between DynamicTestModule and NgModule. That message would be more helpful. But if I am just testing a component here, why my NgModule is involved? The test system is designed with underlying dependency?